# Insert mode arrow keys make letters

Tags: vim, text

In vim, when I am in insert mode and press the arrow keys I get letters instead:

[image: hello]

As you can see, the arrow keys, when pressed, insert a line above the current cursor position including either A, B, C or D.

How do I stop this?

---

## Things I've tried

I have `set nocompatible` in my `~/.vimrc` ([vimrc pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Zuu5eRwg)), I am using pathogen and here is my `~/.vim/bundle` directory:

```
YouCompleteMe/
emmet-vim/
nerdtree/
node/
vim-airline/
vim-markdown/
```

The problem only started recently, but I can't think of what caused it.

I've done `:set term=builtin_ansi`, and this fixes the problem but removes all my colors.

---

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 29 2016 12:51:13)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-2290
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
```

See http://pastebin.com/5z1HbpqW for the whole output.

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

and in vim:

```
:set compatible?
nocompatible

:set term?
term=xterm-256color
```

Comment: [Same question also posted here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9760/51).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
:set term=builtin_ansi
```

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_broken_arrow_key_navigation_in_insert_mode

Comment: This fixes the arrow problem, but now my beautiful vim has no colors/fancy mode bar.